# jstree is not working properly

Tags: php, jstree

I have this array:

```
$arr = array(
    '17-GUIDO HUMBERTO -3 ', 
    array( 
        '2-José-3'
    ),
    array(
        array(
            '18-juan andres-3'
        ),
    ),
    '17-luis -3 '
);
```

I have this function:

```
function listArr($arr) {
    $html = '<ul>';
    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        if (is_array($item)) {
            $html .= listArr($item); // <<< here is the recursion
        } else {
            $html .= '<li>' . $item . '</li>';
        }
    }

    $html .= '</ul>';
    return $html;
}
echo(listArr($tree));
```

Then I add HTML:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="jstree">
                        <?php
                            echo(listArr($tree));
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-md-12 -->
        </div>
```

How can I put `18-juan andres-3` under `17-GUIDO HUMBERTO -3` AND `17-luis -3` under `18-juan andres-3`

`17-luis -3`  **Under**  `18-juan andres-3`   **Under**  `17-GUIDO HUMBERTO -3` **(This is the top)**

How should I put the array to work properly with jstree? Please Help Thanks!!

Comment: if it's jstree then i think you have some jquery code. Also based on documentation you need to create an array in the same format what jstree needed

Comment: @Anant Yes my jquery code is just: $('#jstree').jstree(); no more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your array because they are at different level. Chage your array to this:

```
$arr = array(
        '17-GUIDO HUMBERTO -3 ',
        array(
                '2-Jose-3'
        ),
        array(
                'label',
                array(
                        '18-juan andres-3',
                        array('17-luis -3 '),
                ),
        ),

);
```

and i don't see any `$tree` declared.

call like:

```
echo(listArr($arr));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
17-GUIDO HUMBERTO -3
  -- 2-Jose-3
  -- label
  ---  18-juan andres-3
  ----   17-luis -3
```